# php - passing updated value of variable between functions inside of a class

Tags: php

I was under the impression that the following concept would work, but the new value of $foo isn't passed between functions.  What is the correct way to do this?

```
class doSomething
{

    public $foo = "good";

    public function changeFooAgain()
    {
        $this->foo = "best";
    }

    public function changeFoo()
    {
        $this->foo = "better";

    }   

    public function getFoo()
    {
        $this->changeFoo();
        $this->changeFooAgain();

        return $this->foo;
    }


}

$foo = new doSomething;

print $foo->getFoo();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am under the impression that :

- Your code is correct
- And that the `foo` property is being accessed from each method.

If I execute your code :

- The `getFoo()` method is executed
- In turn,

  - the `changeFoo()` method is executed -- `foo` is now `better`
  - and the `changeFooAgain()` method is executed -- `foo` is now `best`
- `getFoo()` returns the current value of the `foo` property
- And `best` *(which is the last value that was assigned to the `foo` property)* gets displayed